# Update Ui after change in database Occurs

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an App in Android Studio which takes data from RealtimeDatabase Firebase and I have the following method, I can load all data at first run, but when I update the database after the UI does not change nothing:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                MapModel shiftMap = ds.getValue(MapModel.class);

                ViewGroup linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.mapLayout);

                View cell = new View(MainActivity.this);

                GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();

                shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);

                //shape.setColor(Color.rgb(33,150,243));

                if (shiftMap.getOra00() ==1)
                {
                    shape.setColor(Color.rgb(33,150,243));
                }
                else if (shiftMap.getOra00() ==0.5)
                {
                    shape.setColor(Color.rgb(179,229,252));
                }
                else if (shiftMap.getOra00() ==0)
                {
                    shape.setColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }

                shape.setStroke(3, Color.rgb(255,255,255));

                shape.setCornerRadius(5);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                lp.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);

                cell.setLayoutParams(lp);

                cell.setBackground(shape);

                linearLayout.addView(cell);
                Log.i("Operator",  shiftMap.getOperator() + " | " + shiftMap.getOra00() + " | " + shiftMap.getOra01() + " | " + shiftMap.getOra02());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you passed the `eventListener` object to a `addValueEventListener()` method?

Comment: yeep `shiftMap.addValueEventListener(eventListener);`, the problem was that every time i update the database it creates new View's, and the UI was not updated correctly. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my code is that every time that the Database is updated it creates new controls in the UI. I managed to resolve the issue by deleting every control then update the UI, and everything is fine. Below the code:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ViewGroup linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.mapLayout);

            if(linearLayout.getChildCount() > 0)
                linearLayout.removeAllViews();

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                MapModel shiftMap = ds.getValue(MapModel.class);

                View cell = new View(MainActivity.this);

                GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();

                shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);

                //shape.setColor(Color.rgb(33,150,243));

                if (shiftMap.getOra00() == 1)
                {
                    shape.setColor(Color.rgb(33,150,243));
                }
                else if (shiftMap.getOra00() ==0.5)
                {
                    shape.setColor(Color.rgb(179,229,252));
                }
                else if (shiftMap.getOra00() ==0)
                {
                    shape.setColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }

                shape.setStroke(3, Color.rgb(255,255,255));

                shape.setCornerRadius(5);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 50);

                lp.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);

                cell.setLayoutParams(lp);

                cell.setBackground(shape);

                linearLayout.addView(cell);
                Log.i("Operator",  shiftMap.getOperator() + " | " + shiftMap.getOra00() + " | " + shiftMap.getOra01());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
```

the code:

```
ViewGroup linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.mapLayout);

            if(linearLayout.getChildCount() > 0)
                linearLayout.removeAllViews();
```

removes every control inside the linear layout.